# "Bot" label appears next to my username when I delete a comment posted by the Community bot

Tags: bug, status-review, community-user, deleted-comments, user-labels

On [this post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49200):

1. A user asked an off-topic question
2. The community closed it
3. An irrelevant comment was posted by the Community `Bot`
4. I (a moderator) deleted the irrelevant comment
5. My username in the deletion notice has the `Bot` label appended to it as well

Here's a screenshot of the deleted comment, with the `Bot` label erroneously appearing next to my username:

[image: Screenshot of deleted bot comment, listed as being "deleted by Luke Sawczak Bot"]

I'm not a bot, but a mot... I mean, a mod.

Comment: Can confirm, I'm seeing "deleted by Luke Sawczak `Bot` 1 hour ago" below the deleted comment as well.

Comment: Also reported in Ask Ubuntu Meta: [Bug: Moderator not getting the mod tag but being tagged as a bot in mod actions for comments](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19834).